# Old Joomla New server - Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

I've just moved an oldish joomla (2.5.14) site to a newer sever.

My php knowledge is very poor.

The error is as follows.

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /components/com_portfolio/models/portfolio.php on line 46

Line 46 is $this->_params->cat1 = $params->get( 'category1' );

See below

```
function getParamsFD(){
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    // Get the parameters of the active menu item
    if(FD_JVERSION == '16') {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $params = $app->getParams();
        $this->_params->cat1 = $params->get( 'category1' );
        $this->_params->cat2 = $params->get( 'category2' );
        $this->_params->cat3 = $params->get( 'category3' );
        $this->_params->cat4 = $params->get( 'category4' );
        $this->_params->height = $params->get( 'theight' );
        $this->_params->width = $params->get( 'twidth' );
        $this->_params->columns = $params->get( 'columns' );
        $this->_params->rows = $params->get( 'rows' );
        $this->_params->piwidth = $params->get( 'piwidth' );
        $this->_params->powidth = $params->get( 'powidth' );
        $this->_params->dheight = $params->get( 'dheight' );
        $this->_params->shadow = $params->get( 'shadow' );
        $this->_params->gmode1 = $params->get( 'gmode1' );
        $this->_params->gmode2 = $params->get( 'gmode2' );
        $this->_params->gmode3 = $params->get( 'gmode3' );
        $this->_params->gmode4 = $params->get( 'gmode4' );
        $this->_params->tdmode1 = $params->get( 'tdmode1' );
        $this->_params->tdmode2 = $params->get( 'tdmode2' );
        $this->_params->tdmode3 = $params->get( 'tdmode3' );
        $this->_params->tdmode4 = $params->get( 'tdmode4' );
        $this->_params->thmode1 = $params->get( 'thmode1' );
        $this->_params->thmode2 = $params->get( 'thmode2' );
        $this->_params->thmode3 = $params->get( 'thmode3' );
        $this->_params->thmode4 = $params->get( 'thmode4' );
    } else {
```

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: If a 3rd party extension is throwing error messages, then please contact the developer. This is something they should be notified about so they can fix it and release an update

Comment: It is but unfortunately they are no longer available. I'd be quite happy if I could just suppress the message as it appears not to affect the workings in any way.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that your new server has a higher PHP version which is why it's throwing this error.

If you have access to your *php.ini* file, then try changing:

> error_reporting = E_ALL

to:

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT

If you do not have access to this file, then you could do it by adding some PHP code, however this means editing a core file which I would not recommend. Instead, try adding default values to these parameters. The second argument gets used if no value has been specified:

```
$this->_params->cat1 = $params->get( 'category1', 'default' );
```

Do this for **all** the parameters.

I would also recommend you upgrade to Joomla 2.5.27 as you are 13 versions behind

Comment: Thanks Lodder.. I do have access to the php.ini but it's a shared server. I'm afraid that the php above made no difference. I managed to suppress the error though by using error_reporting(0); in the file. I've also updated Joomla as recommended.